# Extract data from Workflow history list item field

Tags: xml, powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to use powershell to extract the ows_Occurred fields value from the xml field in the list item of workflow history list. The xml field item value is

Xml                                : `<z:row xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema' ows_Content
                                     TypeId='xxxx' ows_Event='5' ows_WorkflowInstance
                                     ='{xxxxx}' 
                                     ows_WorkflowAssociation='{xxx}' ows_WorkflowTemplate='{yyyy}' ows_List='{xxxxx}' ows_Item='888' ows_User='8888;#AAA AAAA' ows_Occurred='2017-03-03 07:00:00' ows_Group='0'`

Thanks

Comment: Normally it should get me the field value from xml using  $item.Xml.row.ows_Occured  , but in this case I see the value in xml, but cant retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$xml = [xml]$item.xml
$xml.row | select ows_Occured
or 
$xml = [xml]$item.xml
$date = [datetime]$xml.row.ows_Occurred

I had to do cast of xml format and get the occured value.